# how to find latitude and longitude in iphone4.0?

Tags: iphone

i am new to iphone 
 by using CLLocation i can find latitude and longitude but it is not working in iphonesimulater4.0 working in 3.2.1,please any one tell me how to calculate latitude & longitude in iphone4.0.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Test on a real device, not on the simulator. And if your code doesn't work, you need to show it.

Answer (score 1):

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location =
        [[[mapview userLocation] location] coordinate];

//NSLog(@"Location found from Map: %f %f",
        location.latitude,location.longitude);
```

Answer (score 1):

this concept use in directly in ur app delegte and check it ur latitude and long.

```
#pragma mark locationManager delegate 

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{    
    //if the time interval returned from core location is more than two minutes we ignore it because it might be from an old session
    if(abs([newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate: [NSDate date]]) < 120) 
    {             
        //CLLocation *test = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:-33.857034 longitude:151.035929];

        currentLocation = newLocation;
        coordinates = newLocation.coordinate;

        latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Location only shows on a real device. You may find the values in the `CLLocationManager` will work in the Simulator (possibly from your exchange - although it wont be very accurate) but the blue pin on the map will always be in CA!

Comment: thank you,i can get default that location but it is not working in device4.0.how to that in iphone device4.0.

Comment: Is your app blocked for Location Services? On the iPhone: Settings -> General -> Location Services -> Turn on for your app.

Comment: Also, it might be worth testing that your devices GPS isn't faulty. Open the maps app and press the location button (bottom left corner). If it finds your location on that, you know your phone is good!